# How do I ask user to input percentage in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner and created a program that asks user to input his percentage and tell him whether his result is good or bad. My code is

```
per=float(input('Enter your percentage: '))
if per>80%:
    print('Your result is good')
else:
    print('Your result is bad')
```

But I always get this error

```
    File "<ipython-input-65-ea1a86d3daa1>", line 2
        if per>80%:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to drop the percentage sign `%` in the `if` block. Additionally, in case, the user inputs anything with `%` sign then, you need to take only the numeric parts of the input. Try this :

```
per = input('Enter your percentage: ')
per = per.replace('%', '')   
per = float(per)
if per>80:
    print('Your result is good')
else:
    print('Your result is bad')
```

Comment: But I want user to input in percentage format. For example he can enter "85%'.

Comment: If you want the user to be able to enter something like "80%", you will need to strip out the "%" before converting the input to a numeric type. To do this, you can change the first line to `per=float(input('Enter your percentage: ').replace('%',''))`.